# Values of the synthetic control created by Synth package in R

Tags: r, synth

I'm using the `Synth` package in R. I properly created my `dataprep.out` and `synth(dataprep.out)`. Following, I created my `path.plot` and it's very fine.

Now I want to find the values estimated by `Synth` for my outcome variable for each time period. Where can I find this info, please?

Thanks in advance

I cannot find the values of the outcome variable created by `Synth` throughout my time periods. The plot created by `path.plot` shows the trajectory of the synthetic estimator, but not the values estimated.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the synthetic control values by using the weights obtained with the `synth` function, after aplying it to your `dataprep` object.

Assuming that your `dataprep` object is called `dp`, the observed outcomes for your treated unit are stored in `dp$Y1plot`, and for the donor pool, in `dp$Y0plot`.

Then, suppose that your `synth` object is called `sc`. Now, you just have to make the following matrix multiplication to get the synthetic control outcomes: `cf = dp$Y1plot%*%sc$solution.w`.

Now you can compare the actual outcomes `dp$Y1plot`, with their counterfactuals `cf`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with a minimal working example of the code in addition to the explanation you have already given. In fact, ideally the question author would already do this and give you a starting point for the code in your answer. Still, even if they haven't, it is still good practice to do it yourself for the benefit of the OP as well as any future readers.